# How do I make embed google sheets full width and height in Wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I would like to embed a google excel sheet that adapts to the screen size or at least displays full content on the desktop version. Here is the current code straight from Google. Is there even a way to do this is Wordpress?

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRD8fj_8C79-j9yTl8ei5WhwcE8r1ZA7Lc3ikhGLbh_fRyyCUy4IQWT51sgfR16r8OrgXIiKXodJ5qK/pubhtml?widget=true&amp;headers=false"></iframe>
```

Comment: Have you tried iframe? with 100% width and 100% height.?

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe src="*link to sheets* width=100% height=100%>
```

try this. Width and height 100% will surely occupy your screen.

And if you are asking for wordpress. Maybe you know first time you have to install iframe plugin from wordpress plugins. then only you can use iframes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I am still having some problems. Here is a link to the page where the google excel sheet is embedded. As you can see it is still not showing all the content. https://thomasherr.org/goals/college-plan

Comment: hi, Can you please check that link again? Its showing 404 error.

Comment: I am sorry, I recently updated the permalink in WordPress. Here is the new link https://thomasherr.org/my-goals/college-plan.

Answer (score 0):

Use embed tag:

```html
<embed src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/17OkIgtNdV1flno_783tJm2xWU0NBh7uEmZ5wEXP2E9g/pub?embedded=true" width="100%" style="height: -webkit-fill-available">
```